# Updating embeded components in seaside, without refreshing the whole page

Tags: jquery, ajax, smalltalk, seaside, visual-age

I have a component (ItemTree) which has 3 embeded components. The first (ItemTreeList) is a list of items to select. The second (ItemGIDE) shows properties for the item you selected.

**How do I tell ItemGIDE to update when a new selection is made on ItemTreeList?**

Firstly, This is more complicated than I'm making it out to be. The ItemTreeList has hirarchy with node types and node instances. It has collapsable divs and when clicking on either a top level hirarchy item or an instance below, will set various variables on other objects. So, a whole lot happens on a single click. I've got the ItemTreeList to update itself without refreshing the whole page. Just need to 'Announce' to the other component (ItemGIDE) that it needs to refresh (Again without refreshing the whole page).

- I've got Jquery and Ajax at hand.
- I'm using Visualage Smalltalk 8.5.0
  with Seaside 3.0. 
  -I've been thinking about a call to ItemTree to tell
  its sub components to update?
- I've been thinking about using
  'announce' to 'announce' to other components to update?
- I've been
  doing actual programming for less than 6 months?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The book [Dynamic Web Development with Seaside](http://book.seaside.st/book) contains a draft chapter about JQuery. In there you find an section called [Replace a Component](http://book.seaside.st/book/web-20/jquery/how-to/replace-component) with an example of what you ask for:

```
OuterComponent>>renderContentOn: html
  html div
    id: (id := html nextId);
    with: child.
  html anchor
    onClick: ((html jQuery id: id) load
      html: [ :r | 
        child := OtherComponent new;
        r render: child ]);
    with: 'Change Component'
```

The code shows the render method of the outer component. It assumes that the component has a variable called `child` that is initialized with the component shown in the initial render. Furthermore, it assumes that the component has a variable called `id` that is set during rendering to remember the target DOM node where the child component is rendered. In the AJAX callback of the anchor you replace the child component with `OtherComponent new` and re-render the contents of the target node.

Comment: OtherComponent exists. You saying it should be recreated and replaced?

Comment: Also, coming from pharo, I was hoping I could use something like `self changed` that you find in morphic, heh

Comment: So, this adds inline javascript to the anchor, any solution that would attach events to the anchor in a javascript script block or javascript file?

Comment: This actually worked better than expected. I guess I couldn't get my head around it logically, but, Lukas, Doesn't this leave tons of rogue objects laying around to be garbage collected?

Comment: The amount of memory consumed largely depends on what you do in `OtherComponent`. Apart from that, the code only introduces a callback like any other anchor with a callback block attached.

Comment: `onClick: (html jQuery ajax script: [ :s | s << (s jQuery: #id) html: (OtherComponent new)]);`